# iphone iOS4 access to exchange public folders / calendars

Tags: iphone, exchange-server, ios4

"I'm trying to get iPhone to play nice with all my work calendars that sync over exchange.
My personal calendar works great with adding/remove events. However, my department calendar which is in a public folder does not show up at all. Anyone know a work around?"

When last asked a year ago the answer to this question was that it wasn't possible.  With the release of iOS4 is it now possible to sync iphone to public calendars/folders?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082/iphone-exchange-calendars-in-public-folders

Comment: Don't know the answer, but you might want to take this one over to http://apple.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/ as it's not programming-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to sync public folders to the iPhone (or, for that matter, to Mail or iCal on Snow Leopard). For this reason my department at work uses a shared Google Calendar for tracking everyone's days off, though we're looking into whether the new Outlook:Mac 2011 makes public folders a better idea for us.

Is it possible to subscribe to that public calendar in iCalendar (ICS) format, or to set it up so it is? iOS 4 won't let you subscribe to Exchange public folders, but it will let you subscribe to ICS files. That's read-only but better than nothing.